# content-container class in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I see content-container class in bootstrap templates....  but not find in any bootstrap css file
what is use of this class?
**code is..**

```
<div id="hero-divider" class="content-container homepage_steps">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center">
            <p><i class="hidden-xs hidden-sm fa fa-search"></i></p>            <h3 class="bold sm-nomargin">Search</h3>         <p class="sm-bmargin">Search To Find Members</p>        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center">
            <p><i class="hidden-xs hidden-sm fa fa-check-circle"></i></p>            <h3 class="bold sm-nomargin">Review</h3>           <p class="sm-bmargin">Compare Members You Find</p>      </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center">
            <p><i class="hidden-xs hidden-sm fa fa-comments"></i></p>            <h3 class="bold sm-nomargin">Connect</h3>          <p>Contact Members You Like</p>     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `content-container` class is not from bootstrap.
I suspect your html is from a template where this class is defined in a `<style>` tag or an external css file.